# How to send notifications in Windows 10 (Electron best practise)?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I've tried to use HTML5 Notificaiton API, but it doesn't works on Windows 10. There are alternatives to use?

Comment: Need to be a bit more specific

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for others to help, you'll need to provide some more information. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on how to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your problem.

Comment: You can use node-notifier: https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier

Answer (score 0):

Electron natively supports balloon notification. To show balloon notification, add a tray first and use `tray.displayBalloon(options)` to create a balloon notification. 
Refer [API for tray in electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md)

```
const {app, Tray, Menu} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'icon.png');
let tray;
app.on('ready', function(){
  tray = new Tray(iconPath);
  var contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([    
    {
      label: 'Notify',
      click: function() {
        tray.displayBalloon({
          title:'round',
          content:'world'
        })
      }
    }
  ]);
  tray.setToolTip('This is my application.');
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
});
```

Comment: Did you use it?

Comment: This is the edited answer, which I have tried and works.

Comment: if you have found the answer useful, click on the tick mark next to the answer so it can help others too.

Comment: When you run the app, you'll have a tray icon. You have to right click on the tray icon and click on Notify.

Comment: I know, nothing happens when I click on Notify.

Comment: That is strange, just tried again and it worked. I cloned electron quick starter from electron git repository, replaced the main.js with the above code, and added a placeholder png file icon.png and it worked for me. Have you added the png file?